# RPM: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found on Centos 6 with CUPS 1.7.1

Tags: compiling, rpm, cups

Trying to install CUPS 1.7.1 on Centos 6.5 via RPM, I use:

```
# rpmbuild -ta cups-1.7.1-source.tar.bz2 --without dbus --without libusb1
```

but stops with below error:

```
Checking for unpackaged file(s): 

/usr/lib/rpm/check-files /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/cups-1.7.1-1.x86_64 
error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found: /usr/share/cups/usb/org.cups.usb-quirks

RPM build errors: 
Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found: 

/usr/share/cups/usb/org.cups.usb-quirks
```

Answer (score 16):

This file was installed into the %{buildroot} directory in the %install phase, but was not referenced in the %files. rpmbuild does not allow files in %{buildroot} that are not packed in the %files. So either add it in the %files if the file is needed, or do not install it the %{buildroot}

Comment: The error should not be circumvented, usually; but it can be if necessary, with `%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0`, as mentioned in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514546/1980619).  See [the Fedora Draft Docs](https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s05s07.html) and [Maximum RPM, by Ed Bailey](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-anywhere.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it turns out that the postinstall file that i was creating needed an extra newline at the end because when the spec was being created, the %file was butt ended into my %post entry.